# How to Nonlinear Regression Using MathNet Numerics Lib in C#?

Tags: c#, mathnet-numerics

[image]

I have a function like this. I know that value Ri(mi) and mi (
I have mi and Ri(mi) array).

I need to solve the nonlinear equation using the MathNet Numerics library. 
Reducing the fault most, It must guess the values (a,b,c,T). 
How can I do that?

Comment: I was used Accord.net library, then solved.